# Clues don't lie?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language, affix-riddle

What are we?

> I am a b-ball player in a... (9)

> My prefix is a French degree,
>
> My infix is in Britain, misleadingly,
>
> My suffix is above you,
>
> But my whole is behind. (6)

> A country that recently changed said "Mihail Barışnikov" (name of a store, 2 words)

> I bounce-a bounce-a bounce-a, to the sound of the beat... I am a rabbit, what's the sound of my feet? (3,3)

Comment: [tag:cryptic-clues] refers to cryptic crossword clues, which follow a very specific set of rules - are you sure that's applicable here?

Comment: @Deusovi sorry, my sick body got confused

Comment: I thought maybe:
2=ONPXHC? 4=UVC UBC?

Comment: @Chengarda yes. yes it is.